# Caffe ImageData neural network basic example fails to parse the model file

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to build a minimal example of a neural network with ***IMAGE DATA*** that I have prepared from a CSV file using the caffe libraries.

My prototext is as follows: [wine_train.prototxt]

```
name:"wineclass"
layers {    
  name: "data"
  type: "IMAGEDATA"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  image_data_param {
    source: "examples/wine/test.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
  include{
   phase:TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "IMAGEDATA"
  top: "label"
  top: "label"
  image_data_param {
    source: "examples/wine/train.txt"
    batch_size: 2
  }
  include{
   phase:TRAIN
  }
}
layers {
  name: "ip"
  type: "INNER_PRODUCT"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "ip"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
  }
}
layers {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SOFTMAX_LOSS"
  bottom: "ip"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "ip"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

and my solver is as follows:

```
net: "examples/wine/wine_train.prototxt"
test_iter: 250
test_interval: 1000
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 5000
display: 1000
max_iter: 10000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "wine/train"
solver_mode: CPU
```

Each time I get the following error:

```
LIGH@IVIP2:~/caffe$ build/tools/caffe train -model '/home/shaunak/caffe/examples/wine/wine_train.prototxt' -solver '/home/shaunak/caffe/examples/wine/solver.prototxt'
I0415 04:31:00.154145 57047 caffe.cpp:117] Use CPU.
I0415 04:31:00.154485 57047 caffe.cpp:121] Starting Optimization
I0415 04:31:00.154552 57047 solver.cpp:32] Initializing solver from parameters:
test_iter: 250
test_interval: 1000
base_lr: 0.01
display: 1000
max_iter: 10000
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
stepsize: 5000
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "wine/train"
solver_mode: CPU
net: "examples/wine/wine_train.prototxt"
I0415 04:31:00.154660 57047 solver.cpp:79] Creating training net from net file: examples/wine/wine_train.prototxt
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 4:9: Expected integer or identifier.
F0415 04:31:00.154774 57047 upgrade_proto.cpp:928] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: examples/wine/wine_train.prototxt
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f4a30766c3c  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7f4a30766b88  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7f4a3076658a  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7f4a30769521  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7f4a30b8b1ee  caffe::ReadNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie()
    @     0x7f4a30b6dfa2  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7f4a30b6ee63  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7f4a30b6f036  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @           0x40c3c0  caffe::GetSolver<>()
    @           0x406361  train()
    @           0x4048f1  main
    @     0x7f4a2fe86ec5  (unknown)
    @           0x404e9d  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
LIGH@IVIP2:~/caffe$
```

What exactly does the error say and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `'wine_train.prototxt'` has a problematic format. It mixes old format (i.e., `layers` instead of `layer`, layer types in all capitals) and new format (i.e., layer types as string and not as enumerations).
Remove the quotation marks (`"`) from the layer types and run `$CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin`to get an upgraded net prototxt.

Additionally, you do not need (and probably should not) provide `-model` argument when running `caffe train`. This argument is used when running `caffe test`. The model file is defined in the `solver.prototxt`.